# wcf - difference between MaxConcurrentCalls and MaxConcurrentSessions property

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

After reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentcalls.aspx

I have concluded that:

**MaxConcurrentSessions** is the number of queued sessions per client (default of 10)
**MaxConcurrentCalls** is the number of active connections on the service (default of 16) i.e. all clients accessing the service at any one time, meaning that if 2 client did 10 calls each, 4 would have to wait in the queue for processing.

Questions:

1. Is my conclusion correct?
2. How does **MaxConnections** interact with these?
3. Does **MaxConnections** take precedence over the **MaxConcurrentX** settings?

(Note:I am using .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MaxConcurrentCalls** has to do with the number of calls on the service that are currently executing.

**MaxConnections** has to do with the total number of open connections on the service, regardless if the service is executing anything for the connection.

For example, if a client opens a connection to the service, calls a method, and is waiting for the method to return, it will count against the **MaxConcurrentCalls**. As soon as the service returns a response to the client’s method call, it will not count against the **MaxConcurrentCalls**… even if you didn’t close the client-side proxy. Assuming you didn’t close the client-side proxy, the connection would count towards the **MaxConnections** on the service since you still have the connection open, but it’s not currently executing anything on the service so it would not count against the **MaxConcurrentCalls**.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  Can I ignore MaxConcurrentSessions if I have a per call service instance mode?

Comment: No, I wouldn't ignore MaxConcurrentSessions. Depending on your binding and configuration, a session could automatically be created for each connection. For example, by default the wsHttpBinding will cause a session to be created for each connection. In other words, each time you call Open() on your client-side proxy, a session will be created. The session won't be destroyed until you close your client-side proxy.